# FCM sends me the last notification only if the device is not available

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use FCM to send notifications for Android, it works well in the case of online, but if the device is not available and notifications are sent once it becomes online again, the last notification is sent only from all notifications

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Pleas read the howtoask in the link below. I recommend you to add your code to let us know what you've already tried.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: i used pusher beams which depends on fcm to work with interests i though that the problem was pusher beams but i tried to send many notification from firebase dashboard but the same problem

Comment: i am not working with code for now  i just added firebase and getting notifications in the background